# Gradle exclude property value or file from gradle during build except locally

Tags: java, spring, gradle

So i am not really sure how to ask this question so I am going to try my best.

I currently have a file within my project that is used for SSO oidc configuration. For the most part we do not use it, most of the configuration comes from the dev database. The only value that we do use is the callback url, Which calls back to localhost instead of the dev environment. When my application starts up i check to see if that file exists and pretty much override dev configurations with anything in that file. Mostly so we can just return back to localhost. I also do development work and need to add or change additional values locally so the ability to override is needed for me specifically. So the issue i am trying to find a solution for is when we jar the application that oidc configuration file also gets included and deployed to the server. This then will make the dev environment point to localhost. I tried excluding that oidc configuration file from gradle but then when i run the application locally it also excludes it and then does not have the file locally. I am trying to figure out a way to only exclude that oidc file configuration when deployed to dev/test/prod but keep it locally. Or maybe even a different approach would work too.

Comment: Do you need the file to be compiled within jar for local execution, or it can be excluded and just maintained in repository?

Comment: I only need it for local execution. When it gets deployed to dev/test/prod i do not need the file at all, we can throw it away xD.

Answer (score 0):

For this case, you can create a local directory in your resources folder, then in gradle you can exclude this directory specifically to be bundled when jar is created using below:

```
jar {
    exclude ("DIRECTORY-TO-EXCLUDE/**")
}
```

Comment: I am testing this now.

Comment: I was able to exclude it with 
bootJar {
      exclude("fileName");
}